# Getting active datasource when there are multiple datasources?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0

i am using spring/hibernate application. i configured c3p0 connection pool. my application has 5 datasources which connects to 5 different databases. 5 databases are for 5 different modules. 
when i am using one module it has connected to some datasource. is it possible to get that particular datasource which is being used by the current module?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean the datasource name ?

Answer (score 0):

You must be explicitly selecting a data source for a module. Check in the code.